# how can make disable if the texts are empty with?

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit, disabled-control, submit-button

```
<?php


        echo '<form action="" method="post">
        <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
                <td>Ad:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ad" /><td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td>Soyad:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="soyad"  /><td>
            <tr>
                <td>Yas:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="yas"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>E-Mail</td>
                <td><input type="text"e-mail="E-Mail"  /></td>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Gonder" id="b1"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>';

?>
```

Comment: You want to disable the submit button when the fields are not filled in? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation

Comment: yes but ı couldnt do anything to make disable

Comment: Either implement html5 validation or look into a JavaScript code to do validation.

Comment: the problem is ı dont know js. I found a lot codes. but i couldnt do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use AJAX to do anything with send data to the Server. You want to `return false` on your submit when using AJAX. A simple solution to what you are asking, however, can be done as follows:

```
var frm = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
var els = frm.elements;
frm.onsubmit = function(){
  for(var i=0,l=els.length; i<l; i++){
    if(els[i].value === ''){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```